# Docker run connectionError

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-image

Here is my first attempt to use Docker image to implement Spring Boot app that users Active directory for authentication.

So, I have a Docker image of active directory, downloaded from Docker https://hub.docker.com/r/clcmanagedos/active-directory-services/.

when i try to run the docker image, it throws a Exception.

`$ docker images

REPOSITORY                               TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
clcmanagedos/active-directory-services   latest c1457128bd49  3 months ago   107MB`

```
$ docker run -i -t c1457128bd49 /bin/zsh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7f827fc1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='none', port=8500): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/kv/config/active-directory/db-region (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7f827fc1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "active_directory_services.py", line 28, in <module>
    region_name=kv('db-region'),
  File "active_directory_services.py", line 23, in kv
    index, data = c.kv.get(consul_prefix + key, index=index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/consul/base.py", line 467, in get
    params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/consul/std.py", line 35, in get
    self.session.get(uri, verify=self.verify)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='none', port=8500): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/kv/config/active-directory/db-region (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7f827fc1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve',))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good image, no documentation, no Dockerfile ...

Comment: Find how to install it yourself and build your own image